# Quickly translate strings in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Android Studio has the "Translation Editor" built in, which is a very nice tool, but to quickly translate strings, the user interface is quite a hassle. I have to double-click an item to edit it, where I would expect an <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd> keys to work as well.

Is there a shortcut to enter edit mode in the translation editor?

Comment: This is a real nuisance. Did you find a solution. You can use some online translation editor as an alternative.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure when it got changed, but for everyone (like me) who found this post here. The <kbd>F2</kbd> now works to edit fields without using the mouse.

Comment: What version of Android Studio / OS are you using. I have Android Studio 1.5.1 on Fedora 22, and `F2` doesn't work. The whole editor has become very buggy and completely unusable even.

Comment: I'm on Mac OS X and my Android Studio version is 2.0 Beta 6.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to exit the editor and go to the next required translation too? When I hit enter it jumps back to the top of the list instead of simply the next one. I tried hitting f2 again, down arrow or even shift-enter. All jump to the top instead of the next field down